# Why did NYC swing towards Trump more than surrounding demographically similar area?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, demographics

The combined results of the 5 boroughs of NYC had a swing towards former president Donald Trump of about 9 percentage points. However, the combined results of Hudson Union and Essex counties in New Jersey, right by New York City, only swung 3 points in that direction.

They seem to have similar non-white populations, foreign born populations, etc. Why did NYC swing towards Trump more than three nearby counties in New Jersey that seem similar demographically?

By swing I am also talking about vote margins too. Those 3 counties were won by tens of thousands more votes combined versus 2016. But Biden won NYC by tens of thousands fewer votes.

Additionally Orthodox population doesn't seem to fully explain it. The Bronx which is 55% Hispanic swung 13% while Hudson, 45% Hispanic and more Cuban (a group that Democrats historically don't do so well with, and lost more ground nationally than average), swung only 6%.

I heard that it was because it was NYC had more riots/civil unrest, which studies show might be a part of it. If I were to compare each New Jersey county to a borough in NYC in demographics, here is a good list to try: Hudson ~ Bronx, Union ~ Queens/Manhattan, Essex ~ part of Brooklyn.

Note: this question is one vote away from reopening. I want someone to see this so they can choose whether to reopen it and cast the deciding vote.

Comment: You need to include more details in your post; it took me a good 10 minutes to figure out what you were comparing and where you got those numbers. Typically, people use the word 'swing' as a change from one side (Democrat) to the other (Republican), when your statistics depend on it not being a zero-sum game (ie, more voters voted in 2020, and we're comparing 2016 Trump numbers to 2020 Trump numbers).

Comment: I agree, please link to your data so we can investigate. Seems to me that there's probably way too few Orthodox Jews to account for this but I don't know how many people make up a 9-pt swing in NYC

Comment: I know. The Orthodox Jewish population seems like a possible cause. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews_in_New_York_City -- there was a large Hispanic swing towards Trump but that doesn't account for the difference between those areas.

Comment: I vote to reopen because I edited to add a little bit more details.

Comment: Have you considered that simply choosing to live in NYC, or not, might be a more significant demographic difference than any of those you list?

Answer (score 5):

The answer may lay (at least partially) in the Orthodox Jewish community. While NYC has a large Orthodox Jewish community (one of the biggest in the world), Orthodox Jewish presence in Newark, Orange, Jersey City, Union City, etc. is very small.

According to a poll conducted by Ami Magazine, Donald Trump's approval rate in the Orthodox Jewish community has risen during his Presidential term from 54% to 89%.
https://www.amimagazine.org/2019/12/19/trumps-support-among-orthodox-jews-is-at-89-percent-poll-2/

Another cause may be the fact that the George Floyd protests in that part of NJ were almost always peaceful, unlike the heavy rioting that took place in NYC - which drove many people to move towards Donald Trump.
See https://www.northjersey.com/story/news/coronavirus/2020/05/31/why-newark-nj-protest-remained-peaceful-while-others-turned-violent/5300613002/

Comment: That was a suspect in my mind. I thought about that but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that that "rioting" drove people in NYC towards Trump? Also, the article you linked to doesn't support your claim that protests were more quiet in NJ than NY. While this one protest in Newark was peaceful, it mentions clashes with police in Trenton and Atlantic City.

Comment: https://politicalkiwi.wordpress.com/2021/05/13/civil-unrest-in-kenosha-helped-donald-trump/ -- look. The rioting seems like a part. Not NYC specifically but seems relevant.

Comment: @divibisan, Trenton and Atlantic City are outside of the region discussed in this question.